# SpringContext in REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets

generally we use Spring context in servlet as follows

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servlet.getServletContext());
SomeBean someBean = (SomeBean) ctx.getBean("someBean");
```

But in REST service declared using annotation is not actually servlet. So we do not get getServletContext()

How handle this ?

**answer**
1) By passing context as parameter to method

```
@GET
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String createCustomer(@Context ServletContext servletContext){
```

2) Other solution is using  ApplicationContextAware
which is explained [here](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that, you should be using dependency injection. When you are doing lookups, you generally need to take a step back and rethink.

Comment: @M.Deinum did you mean using  ApplicationContextAware which I have mentioned above edits ?

Comment: No... I mean dependency injection. You shouldn't use the `ApplicationContext` directly to obtain beans. You should have those injected.

Comment: @M.Deinum But objects of my service class are not created by REST framework, right ? I do not create them through getBean. So how can I use dependency injection. Can you please write detailed answer or give URL where it is explained.

Comment: If you can use `ApplicationContextAware` you can use dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the application context you can have your service implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). Then when the service is created, Spring will call the `setApplicationContext` method to provide you with the application context. Inside that method you can then store the provided context for later use.